# Regex, grouping, find last match

Tags: regex

I was hoping this regex

```
([A-Z]+)$
```

would pick the last occurance in this example:

```
AB.012.00.022ABC-1
AB.013.00.022AB-1
AB.014.00.022ABAB-1
```

But I get no matches. If I remove the '$' I get:

```
AB and ABC
AB and AB
AB and ABAB
```

I only want the last occurance (ABC / AB / ABAB). 
"AB." should not return a match. How to ignore it? Something like (^??.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last occurrence, just use a positive look-ahead that will tell the regex engine to match the final symbols at the end:

```
([A-Z]+)(?=-\d+$)
```

Your regex just looks for the capital letters from A to Z at the end of a string, but there are no uppercase letters at the end of neither `AB.012.00.022ABC-1`, nor `AB.013.00.022AB-1`, nor `AB.014.00.022ABAB-1` (they all end with `-1`). If your strings all have `-1` at the end, you can use `(?=-1$)` look-ahead.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY5jO0/1)

Comment: Worked perfect! But I must look into what that positive lookahead does :-)

Comment: Here is another :): `([A-Z]+)(?=[^A-Z]*$)` - it will also do what you expect as it allows no letters from A to Z up to the end. See https://regex101.com/r/lY5jO0/2.

Comment: Is it possible to write without the look-ahead? Every string starts with "AB." and every string ends with "-\d".

Comment: Strange, it doesn't ignore "AB.", but returns the whole input...
I don't understand why ([A-Z]+)^\. won't work. To me it looks like "capture A-Z groups NOT followed by a "." ...

Comment: If you do not want to capture `AB.`, you need to capture what is after it and only use that capturing group: `^AB\.(.*-\d)$`. Move the parentheses around to get your required output. If you provided exact sample input and output *and* the language you are using, it would be easier to show you a possible solution.

Comment: Sample data has correct format, and it's  (ABC / AB / ABAB) I want. Language is Oracle SQL

Comment: Please try `REGEXP_REPLACE(some_name, '^AB\..*?([A-Z]+)-[[:digit:]]$', '\1') "REGEXP_REPLACE"`.

Answer (score 1):

To match the last occurrence of anything, you can use a negative lookahead that matches what you want later on in the string. This would look like `[A-Z]+(?!.*[A-Z])` where `[A-Z]` is replaced with anything you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Z` which is the absolute end of string meta character.

To get the final line starting with ABC / AB / ABAB, you can do:

```
^((?:ABC|AB|ABAB)\.\S+)\Z
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG2gE8/1)

For the final part of the string that starts with those letters:

```
((?:ABC|AB|ABAB)-\d+)\Z
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG2gE8/3)

If you want each group of    at the end of each line:

```
(ABC|AB|ABAB)-\d+$    # with the M flag
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG2gE8/4)